# How to encode raw response? (Using AndroidNetworking lib, OkHttp)

Tags: android, okhttp, android-networking

I'm trying to read the raw response from an API call.

I'm using:

**com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.0**

which is built on okhttp.

So I would like to log the raw response of an API call.

As far as I know,  **response.body().string();** is only callable once. And it is already called by the library on some point, so I cannot use that.

So I have using:

```
  ResponseBody responseBodyCopy = response.peekBody(Long.MAX_VALUE);
  String rawResp = responseBodyCopy.string();
```

But when I use this, I got the raw response like this:

12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): URL: https://myurl.hu/api/mobile/api.php?method=something

```
12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): Param: param1=12345
12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): Param: param2=abcdef


12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): Header: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): Header: Content-Length: 40
12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): Header: Host: myurl.hu
12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): Header: Connection: Keep-Alive
12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): Header: Accept-Encoding: gzip
12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): Header: User-Agent: okhttp/3.6.0


12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): HTTP Status code: 200
12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): Raw response: ??????????????\ks??+?>[GD?n?i3?u:Izs??@$(?? ?(????C???Mcy<cr?H????aC  ??fyV??QF????fFq???@??‘d??????$N?`4??Z??
????YN?????!>3"?e?5b?@#AkNRP|~?????????)I??+??$?]I?w%!?J?"Y+})-?? ?7[???@??F??e?r?.?L?#?0?rg?T???f?8ohGq?:???B????tGr-A/$   ?I?/Z??V???g@d?l@4?^??8?I???9??r?|??w?=??<QiH;2~?t?/??q???iDQ???VV?'x_&6\???|E???G??3~b??E???aG(u??B?b@7[????????w ?`x???!6*E?g???H??????r?8??)B?%,??+??&?]??"?)?K?a?Sk????T???y??r?'B  ???H???fQ"ow2JB?,??1????8:??{?????(o:??H??f?FN??x$?k??_Y??+K?.k?n?H:??}\?lp?tj?2??\????h?8h???5?    ????%??1N?i:????q?? ???0f??o????????_3vK3^d??|k1?0??u?"/????????E?X??<?k?Cin??"?u??8?   N2_?*$E?
12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): ???b?
12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): ?? C?t?Q_??t?L???2?<.? ?!{???'??N?i??x1????h?O?g???L?<?H??????
12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): ???1??o#??c
12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): ?????.?????n_?*9n???<??    ?I{??;"F??J??M?x???8??7B;Ez??\TI??z??$o70????KHm??D0s@a???2C????ZNjq??????RS??f?E?$4U?e?(r???"z?6-?:??!?8?S??$,? ????cQ?~D??WXEE*?*8;????6eyB?q*y-O??o???????????s?%iK {??a?3`??]??h??????n ##?
W???(?di7????<?7q.b?l??C?;?0q=?H??/????z??)??R_?$   k??:????H??:?e?E????8?a?[?YD?E??}9??s<?? ??3N<??lr}?? x? ?ta??f?e?c??)y'?R???B9
12-11 09:41:30.564: I/RealInterceptor(5416): y3??WU??f%x?<!?Ic?2n??@#?l???4?    ?$M^V?$?cV??1?v
?k?(??)?L.O(]??pt?*]????3??????l?q??<?_;~????jOG??^??B???#? ?!?K?   ??+??VU?cIx????n L|?-0#????I?y??y?@'E*?$?????uy??+[?@???0?U64#?v_??(`o???q?8e??\O??n??O???R???k??w*I?%@_?s?I?a?5???5?Y,2?{_U?!?
???Eb3?|^ x??D[^????V??O?????r????j???????s???????C?????U+???}?Z=?^?v%?<?K2????@ă?p?V?"??Eq?Q?+?6?U?????e26???? ??@??U;A?S???E?riek?dX[?w???H\????8%?,%?yšp????g{??ap????g??|!@;?a@?2???QlK(V$X/?#????>do???Zcbwb?9??i?*RUP??S??M??^?UH?{2? S??M?.?c??x???`??Ŕ???=??Ae?AE?u?=???&??i??????6?+C7d???~Q?+p;*[??#??F??U?jV??????e?jZ????u?k??-Q"m]?`N?????uw?Z#M?2??o$??H?C0?dfNN4?????d????aX??C-T???"o????????Y?C?????????Lx\??l?$?Ob=?/?,????g???*??3??d?c
```

So what is this?

Any idea or help what should I do how should I encode this or something to be human readable?

I have tried to encode it to UTF8 but it's not the case :)

EDIT:

I have tried to ungzip it as @Selvin told me so:

```
    public static String decompress(final byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
    final StringBuilder outStr = new StringBuilder();
    if ((compressed == null) || (compressed.length == 0)) {
        return "";
    }
    if (isCompressed(compressed) ) {
        final GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed));
        final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "UTF-8"));

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            outStr.append(line);
        }
    } else {
        outStr.append(compressed);
    }
    return outStr.toString();
}

public static boolean isCompressed(final byte[] compressed) {
    return (compressed[0] == (byte) (GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC)) && (compressed[1] == (byte) (GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC >> 8));
}
```

Now it only returns this:

```
12-11 10:08:33.155: I/RealInterceptor(6289): Raw response: [B@59864f3
```

Comment: ungzip it ... also what is the point of using "android-networking" over plain okhttp in your case?

Comment: it seeems like you log `byte[].toString()` not results of `decompress(...)`